# "www" in URL is causing a 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a very strange issue where having "www." in my URL is causing a 404. I temporarily edited my .htaccess file to password protect the domain for development. I have since restored access and now if I go to www.domain.com it returns a 404.

However, going to domain.com works. The host provider is hostgator, and per their .htaccess guide (http://support.hostgator.com/articles/-htaccess-guidance) I have reverted back to the default config with the same situation:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.php default.html home.html
```

I have even gone as far as deleting .htaccess alltogether in hopes that it would restore but no such luck.

What needs to happen here to allow a website to be accessed via "www.domain.com" and "domain.com?"

Answer (score 2):

Your .htaccess file looks good as it stands; there is nothing preventing it through www.domain.com. The most likely issue here is an IP propagation one. www.domain.com is technically a subdomain of domain.com. Therefor, they use different IP addresses. It's possible that HostGator has cached the .htaccess information incorrectly for one IP, and not the other.

First port of call, try pinging both domains. Open up Command Prompt, and type:

```
ping www.domain.com
ping domain.com
```

See if one of them times out.

Ultimately, give it a few days, and try again. Your .htaccess file *should* copy over automatically, and the problem should be resolved. It's also possible that HostGator has configured something incorrectly on their end.

If after a few days simply waiting doesn't fix the issue, take it up with HostGator, or *forcibly* redirect your users to the non-www site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I played the waiting game for about a week with no positive results. As a temporary work around I'll probably use a re-direct to non www until I can get in touch with hostgator to see what the scoop is.

Comment: Good luck. If you've waited that long, then yeah, something is probably wrong on their end, and you should get in touch. Your .htaccess file is definitely solid though :)

Comment: For what it's worth I even tried your htaccess solution and it still did not work...

Comment: Then there is definitely something funky going on with HostGator. Get in contact, and see if they're able to find anything wrong with your account. Sorry I can't be more help, but you've done everything right in this case :)